# C++ (seemingly) Random Compiler Errors

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, allegro

I've been playing around with C, C++ and Allegro thanks to a little book and a bigger book I found in an Oxfam book shop.
I'm understanding it quite well at the moment but I've hit a wall... Whenever I compile I get these errors:

```
archiboldian@archiboldian:~/Documents/C++ Projects/particles$ g++ particles.c -lalleg -lnoise -o particles
particles.c:19: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
particles.c:20: error: ‘Vector2D’ does not name a type
particles.c:21: error: ‘Vector2D’ does not name a type
particles.c: In function ‘int main()’:
particles.c:26: error: ‘nPos’ was not declared in this scope
particles.c:28: error: ‘nVel’ was not declared in this scope
particles.c:29: error: ‘nvel’ was not declared in this scope
particles.c:31: error: ‘addParticle’ was not declared in this scope
particles.c: At global scope:
particles.c:47: error: ‘Vector2D’ has not been declared
particles.c:47: error: ‘Color’ has not been declared
particles.c: In function ‘void addParticle(int, int, Vector2d, int, int, int)’:
particles.c:50: error: ‘particles’ was not declared in this scope
```

And this is my code...

```
#include "allegro.h"

struct Vector2d{
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct Particle {
    Vector2d Pos;
    Vector2d Vel;
    int age;
    int LifeSpan;
    int colour;
    int size;
};

int max = 50;
int pcount = 0;
Particle particles[max];

int main(void) {

    Vector2D nPos;
    Vector2D nVel;

    nPos.x = 320;
    nPos.y = 240;
    nVel.x = 2;
    nvel.y = 0;

    addParticle(10, nPos, nVel, 20, makecol(255,255,255), 2);

    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();

    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640, 480, 0, 0);

    while(!key[KEY_ESC]) {
        for(int i=0;i<pcount;i++){

        }
    }

    allegro_exit();
}

void addParticle(int addp, Vector2D Pos, Vector2d Vel, int LifeSpan, Color colour, int size) {
    for(int i=0;i<addp;i++){
        pcount++;
        particles[pcount].Pos = Pos;
        particles[pcount].Vel = Vel;
        particles[pcount].LifeSpan = LifeSpan;
        particles[pcount].colour = colour;
        particles[pcount].size = size;
    }
}

END_OF_MAIN();
```

From what I gather from the debug output the first error is talking about a problem with the 
'Particle particles[max];' line and the message sounds like it's wrong to have this '[max]' at the end of 'particles' but that was working fine and compiling without problems until now. It's probably just a typo or a misunderstanding or something but I really can't figure it out.

As you can see it's an attempt at a particle system and any hints on bettering (is that a word?) my code are greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: try declaring max as `const int max = 50`

Comment: `Vector2D` or `Vector2d`... Pick one... ;)

Comment: The question is tagged C++ and C but the questions is asking about C++ while the file name indicates C. C++ and C are two different languages. You're also compiling the file as C++. Pick one...

Answer (score 7):

For a variable to be able to be used as an array size, it needs to be a constant expression. This is denoted with `const` in C++. In C, you'd use a `#define`.

```
// C++
const int MAX = 50;
/* C */
#define MAX 50
/* both C & C++ */
enum { MAX = 50 };
Particle particles[MAX];
```

Comment: In in both languages you could also use an `enum` constant.

Comment: @Jens: I knew I forgot something! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error explains the problem:

```
particles.c:19: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

The fix:

```
const int max = 50;
```

Now the array bound is an integer constant.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the connection between the error and the problem.

Answer (score 1):

VLA is not allowed in the Standard C++.

Use this:

```
const int max = 50;
```

Because array size must be a constant expression. Without `const` keyword, `max` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `const int max = 50;` which is a compile time constant, so it can be used to initialize the array.  (Note that not *all* `const` variables are compile time constants)

<strike>Also, rename the file to `*.cpp`, so GCC will understand the C++ constructs.  It seems to be compiling as straight up `C` language code.</strike>
Joachim Pileborg observed you have both `Vector2d` and `Vector2D`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this code would ever compile.

- `Vector2D` is not a correct type. `struct Vector2D` is. (Many errors arise because of this). You can use `typedef struct Vector2D Vector2D` to get the expected behaviour. Not sure what's going on there with the `Vector2d` (lowercase `d`).
- You cannot dynamically define the space of a global table variable. If you do `particles[50]` it will work. It will also work if you `#define max 50` or `enum { max = 50 };`. Where, for such purposes, the enum variant is probably your best bet. Otherwise, you may opt to dynamically allocate space for particles using `malloc()` — you would have to do this in `main()`. The problem here is that `int max = 0;` is not constant. Defining it `const` will not help if you are using C, as it means read-only rather than constant.

Comment: Your first point about `Vector2D` vs `struct Vector2D` does not apply to C++.  Your second point is also C specific. While the filename used in the question indicates the language is C the question title says C++ and the file is being compiled as C++.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that then. I looked through the code and didn't see any C++ specific things, so I simply assumed it was C.
But I'm interested — if I got this right, in C++, structs are automagically typedefd for you? I haven't done a lot of (or any) C++. :)

Comment: It's not so much that they're magically typedef'd as it is that C++ just allows one to refer to structs without the struct keyword. Maybe it's pedantic to draw a distinction, but one difference is that even inside a struct's definition you can use the struct's unadorned name, whereas with typedefs you couldn't do that: `C++: struct Foo { Foo *f; };`

Comment: So I'm assuming it's incredibly bad practice in C to have something like a typedef'd type "A", and a type "union A" and a type "struct A" where they're all different? Or are there cases where this is OK?

I'm writing a small virtual machine for the hypothetical SIC processor and am using a union of bit field structs to parse instructions, where the union has the same name as the raw "instruction" typedef.

Comment: I believe it's not actually legal in C to use the same tag with a struct and a union at the same time, though I don't have a citation for that. My C compiler rejects it, anyway. Having a typedef for a struct shadow the struct name works in both C and C++. Having a typedef shadow the name of a different struct type works in C, but causes an error in C++. I probably would avoid using the same name for different types, but if you're not expecting the program to need to be built as C++ it may not matter. I wouldn't go so far as to call it incredibly bad practice.

Comment: I was just using the same tag for a typedef and a union, not a struct at the same time, so I haven't actually tried that. Anyway, thanks for the help!